# Google Analytics does not track data

Tags: angular, typescript, drupal, server-side-rendering

Google analytics does not seem to track any data on our website. How it works;

1. Tracking code get's added in Drupal headless backend cms
2. Dynamic front-end get tracking code by concept(type of site)
3. Tracking get's dynamiccly added to the Head (using angular, in the constructor).

Tag assistant says:

Missing Analytics.js script
&
No HTTP response detected

Tried multiple things, also use code in body, get different kind of trackings etc. Als tried adding

Current used code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 991964869 --> <script data-cfasync="false" async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-991964869-1"></script>

<!-- Cross domain checking for the ticket sale cms-->
<script data-cfasync="false">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-37890526-1');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-37890526-1', 'auto');
  ga(function (tracker) {
    var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    var frameWindow = document.getElementById('cm-ticketshop').contentWindow;
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      if (event.origin === "pos.cmtickets.com" && event.data === "shop.loaded") {
        frameWindow.postMessage({
          clientId: clientId
        }, '*');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Cross domain checking for the ticket sale cms -->
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code --> <script>
  ! function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
    if (f.fbq) return;
    n = f.fbq = function () {
      n.callMethod ?
        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
    };
    if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];
    t = b.createElement(e);
    t.async = !0;
    t.src = v;
    s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
  }(window, document, 'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '324909954561696');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script> <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=324909954561696&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
      /></noscript> 
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Want the tracking to work! :(

Comment: Coz Google Analytics works well in MPAs (Multi-Page Applications) and I think you are using it on Angular which is SPA follow this tutorial hope it will help you https://codeburst.io/using-google-analytics-with-angular-25c93bffaa18

Answer (score 1):

make sure you just copy paste the code provided by Google analytics api, i have following code pasted at the last inside `<head></head>` tag of index.html file and its working and tracking the data

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-134123456-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-134123456-1'); 
  </script>
```